# azure cosmos db : How to manage users'tokens and connection string for cosmos db

Tags: azure, token, azure-cosmosdb, connection-string, azure-rbac

On Azure cosmos DB, I want to have a user with access only to DATA plane (no CONTROL plane).
Following the REST API (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/cosmos-db/create-a-user) I am able to create a user then to grant him permissions.
Now, I'm stuck with control of the Token.
I can get it automatically when setting the permissions. But no more.
Besides, why should it be included in the connection string
Getting a permit, enables me to get the Token for example

"_token": "type=resource&ver=1&sig=/l3kOULV1Vjk+ZnBqUmzow==;dkMrrNO/x8YperU6omZmUmNcwPCXPmpWUFtB3HFFNlqxvGCJsx0tk2IjOPVYf/jV53fAxaBq9vrB7eXG5dgGAJWCTzm1A0L1Hi5FMeo5uxrDn3be3ySifJxKe0uby6eAQ4XrQUKHwGz14y9fkBxuHt8GoZlFEWo5hZHyuSv/hOvvxeM7N4BBIbEiToGiZjt+g6Gx5qvipGMd16X//EpvWs8EXHMUBqf4x0KR4WODiBs=;"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tokens are only valid for an hour but you can override this and extend for up to five hours. [Permissions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/cosmos-db/permissions)

If you will be using resource tokens to manage access to Cosmos you will need to implement a token broker to manage this. There are two examples I can point you to.

[Token broker for a Xamarin mobile app](https://github.com/Azure/azure-cosmos-dotnet-v2/tree/master/samples/xamarin/UserItems/ResourceTokenBroker/ResourceTokenBroker/Controllers)

[Token broker created by Citrix in Java](https://github.com/terry-citrix/tokenbroker)

Hope this is helpful.

Comment: Thanks Mark, I see the point. I thought of the SAS for Storage Accounts but it's not the same case.